# Question about making UIView disappear from screen in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I want to show the View for a few seconds and make it disappear from the screen.

[image]

If I wait 10 seconds on this screen

[image]

I want to make this view go off screen.

How can I animate the view slowly descending down?

code...

```
fileprivate func setupViewToAnimate(view: UIView) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 10, options: .curveEaseInOut , animations: {

        }) { _ in

        }
    }
```

Comment: In the `animations` closure, you can either (a) update the `frame` to where you want it to move (offscreen); (b) update its `center` (again, off screen) or (c) update the constraints and call `layoutIfNeeded`.

Comment: Also in animation you can set alpha 0 to 1 with animation and after completion of animation you can hide or remove view or viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Timer` to schedule the dismiss of your snackBar/notification view. it will be triggered after the completion of animation for showing your view. Please check the following code for the same.

```
private let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
let snackbarView = UIView()

fileprivate func setupViewToAnimate() {
    let targetYPost = snackbarView.frame.origin.y
    let dismissTimerLength = 3.0 
    snackbarView.frame.origin.y = keyWindow.frame.height 

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
          self.snackbarView.frame.origin.y = targetYPost
          }, completion: {
          _ in
             Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(dismissTimerLength), target: self, selector: #selector(self.hideSnackbarView), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    })
}

  //After 3.4 sec snack bar will be hidden
@objc private func hideSnackbarView() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                self.snackbarView.frame.origin.y = self.keyWindow.frame.height
        }, completion: {
            _ in
            self.snackbarView.isHidden = true
        })
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
  private func setupViewToAnimate(view: UIView, bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 10, options: .curveEaseInOut , animations: {
      // Set the bottomConstraint to minus the height of the view so it gets entierly hidden
      bottomConstraint.constant =  -view.frame.height
      // Tell the view to re-layout its subviews again so we have something to animate
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { _ in
      // If the animation is completed, we can remove the view from the superview since we don't need it anymore
      view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
  }
```